# swift check which tab bar item was clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am using a tab bar controller and I wonder if there is a way to check which tab is being clicked?

If the user clicks on the "account" tab and is not logged in I want to redirect to a full screen modal login screen instead of the account VC.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in your custom UITabBarController or somewhere, and override the 'didSelectItem' function.

```
import UIKit

class TabbarViewController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
}

    override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {
    print("Selected Index :\(self.selectedIndex)");
}

}
```

Comment: how cancel change other view controller ?

Answer (score 0):

In the scenario you outlined, I would check to see if current user is logged in or not, and if not segue to the appropriate screen of your application.

Comment: Thats what I want to do. But how do check if the account tab is being clicked so that I can check what segue I should fire?

Comment: o, yea use the delegate method as Sausage commented

Answer (score 0):

UITabBarDelegate's didSelectItem

Answer (score 0):

The options that others have provided are fine, but I wanted to let you know of another way. In the viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, or viewDidLoad functions, you can call what you need to segue to a login ViewController